# AdMob. Правильно ли сформирован рекламный баннер?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли сформирован рекламный баннер ?

Не сжат ли он?
Мне кажется значки (i,x), отмеченные стрелкой, находятся не на своем месте?! Должны быть справа?! Не так ли?

Если я прав, то как исправить ситуацию? )

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ll_rekl2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"> 
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Баннер]

Comment: да нормально всё. не вы эти значки рисуете, не вам и заботится о их местоположении.

Comment: Спасибо, Pavel, за мнение!